# Visual Studio Upgrade 2010 to 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio, telerik, resharper

I currently use Visual Studio 2010 Professional.  I’m thinking of upgrading to Visual Studio 2015 Professional.

I do quite a lot of development work on early versions of .Net 2.0 / 3.5 (not by choice, but to support legacy apps)

Given this is there anything I should be aware of when migration, can you still develop earlier .net apps?

I also use Telerik and Resharper tools

TIA.

Comment: IMHO you shouldn't have any problems. But if you develop also c/c++ libraries redist will change/upgrade so you will have to consider this (in docs, install guidelines etc.). There are also some changes in tests - test explorer window, ordered tests etc.

Comment: I have one .NET 2.0 app that will not build in 2013 or 2015 (only 2010), but I haven't bothered to diagnose why so there could be an easy solution. I'd strongly advise backing up the current project files before 2015 converts them to a newer format (although that should be obvious :P).

Comment: Ok thanks, looks like I'll still be able to create .net 2.0 apps, just pay attention when undergoing the conversation.